# HTTPURLSession digest authentication with HA1 (not password)

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, nsurlsession, digest-authentication

Simply I have scenario where digest authentication is performed using `user name` and `HA1` value (which was calculated somewhere in the past or it was provider by authentication to other server). Password is not available.

Now how do I handle this scenario using `NSURLSession`?

Do I have to do it manually (calculate `HA2` and `response` my self) or is there some solution for that? (it should be there since keeping password as plain text is a security issue).

Please note the I have scenario where `HA1` comes from authentication to other server so `NSURLCredential` [persistence](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCredential_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLCredential/persistence) with value `NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent` doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: looks like I have to do own implementation of digest authentication.